# Where should HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/") go?

Tags: asp.net-core, carter

I'm a bit confused about the `~` path in Asp.NET 6.x

Assume my Web site is hosted on IIS at: `http://somesite.org/special/`

I'm using Carter Lib but I don't think that should matter.

```
    public LogoutModule()
    {
        Get("/api/admin/logout", async ctx =>
        {
            await ctx
               .SignOutAsync("Cookies")
               .ConfigureAwait(false);

            ctx.Session.Clear();
            ctx.Response.Redirect("~/");
        });
    }
```

I thought the redirect would go to `http://somesitename.org/special` but instead it goes to:

```
http://somesitename.org/special/api/admin/~/
```

Redirecting using `ctx.Response.Redirect("/");` doesn't work either. It then goes to:

```
http://somesitename.org/
```

In general I don't know the virtual directory this site is hosted in. I thought the `~` operator took care of that. What don't I understand here?

Comment: Can you share what's in the `Location` header in the HTTP response on the client side?  My assumption is the `~` is simply not being expanded and is being instead used verbatim.

Comment: There's no `Location` header in `HttpContext.Request.Headers`. Should there be?

Comment: If possible, you could try to know the virtual directory name and then try `/Special`. If that not possible and if you are hosting the site on the IIS then you could try using URL_Rewrite/Redirect may help to fix the issue.